# jQuery call to asp.net web method is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a asp.net web method like following

```
[WebMethod]
public string getDate() 
{
   return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

And my jQuery ajax call is following

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "jqueryAjax/Default.aspx/getDate",
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
   {
      alert(errorThrown+"what's wrong?"+XMLHttpRequest);
   },
   success: function (msg) 
   {
      alert(msg);
      // Do something interesting here.
   }
});
```

For some reason my jQuery ajax error handler is getting called. success method is not calling.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `errorThrown` ?

Comment: @JustinIurman the errorThrown is [object Object]

Comment: Well, i mean, what error informations do you get **into** that object ? Also, do you reach your webmethod via `domain.com/jqueryAjax/Default.aspx/getDate` ?

Comment: @JustinIurman and how can I check that?

Comment: `console.log(errorThrown);` or even better `console.dir(errorThrown);` and look into your browser's console to fetch your object

Comment: @xyz: You need to write your web method as static
like this
`[WebMethod]
public static string getDate() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your web method should be static

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getDate() 
{
   return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: any idea how can I return xml from web method and parsing in javascript or jquery